# Why is there a strange trail behind aircraft during landings, and how do I fix it?

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

In *Microsoft Flight Simulator* (2020), when any type of aircraft is landing, a strange trail follows the aircraft (see attached picture), and this happens at any airport. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Aircraft Landing 1]

The trail is the white sheet, and the plane is on top of the sheet.

Comment: i'm not sure what trail or plane you're referring to but i don't see either

Comment: The trail is the white sheet, & the plane is on top of the sheet

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a graphical bug. Did you upgrade your driver. Maybe lower the setting but it seems that the game isn't able the load the smoke textures which gives this glitches. A clean re-install could fix it too.